# Solr Cell NoSuchMethodError

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr

I am trying to get Solr up and running with Solr Cell.

In order to do that I installed Solr using `apt-get install solr`.
I have now managed to set it all up but when updating documents with a PDF document, the following error is produced (by running `curl "http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/update/extract?literal.id=1&commit=true" -F "myfile=@/home/vagrant/test.pdf"`):

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.28 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
        at org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler.inform(ExtractingRequestHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.getWrappedHandler(RequestHandlers.java:244)
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handleRequest(RequestHandlers.java:231)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1317)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:338)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
        at org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler.inform(ExtractingRequestHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.getWrappedHandler(RequestHandlers.java:244)
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handleRequest(RequestHandlers.java:231)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1317)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:338)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error (org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
        at org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler.inform(ExtractingRequestHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.getWrappedHandler(RequestHandlers.java:244)
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handleRequest(RequestHandlers.java:231)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1317)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:338)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.28</h3></body></html>
```

I installed Solr Cell using the following commands:

```
mkdir -p /usr/share/solr/lib
cd ~
wget http://apache-mirror.dkuug.dk//lucene/solr/3.2.0/apache-solr-3.2.0.tgz
tar -xvf apache-solr-3.2.0.tgz
cd apache-solr-3.2.0/
cp dist/apache-solr-cell-3.2.0.jar /usr/share/solr/lib/
cp contrib/extraction/lib/*.jar /usr/share/solr/lib/
/etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you didn't update the Solr `war`. `SolrResourceLoader.getClassLoader()` is a relatively recent addition.

Comment: @phidah: overwrite the war file you have now with the war in apache-solr-3.2.0.tgz